# "Is there any library in Python or software for analyzing raw chromatography data?"

Tags: concentration, software, chromatography

[image]I have taken the data directly from the FID sensor using a DAQ, so I have the chromatography data in this format:
(2 data colummns in a txt file) (18000 rows)

- Time (s) Intensity (V)
- 0.00367___0.0008
- 0.00530___0.00049
- 0.00672___0.00025
- 0.00808___0.00009
- 0.01014___0.00057
- 0.01290___0.00128
- 0.01545___0.00136
- 0.01809___0.00112

I have this data in 2 minutes cycle.

Is there any way I can process this data and obtain the gas concentrations? I understand that a calibration run is required, but what I'm most interested in right now is finding the areas, peaks, and retention times."

Thanks

Comment: For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration [SE meta - formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) // [SE meta -  tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)  // [Advanced formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know)

Comment: Did you consider a *search by topic* e.g. on [PyPI.org](https://pypi.org/search/?q=chromatography)?  Though not yet tested myself on chromatography data, there are reports [fityk](https://fityk.nieto.pl/) equally works well on chromatograms, too

Comment: Googling ‘python chromatography’ yields multiple results.

Comment: The biggest problem here is determining peak boundaries and the baseline.. What vendor are you using? Do you have raw data files instead of the table?

Comment: I have a table of intensity and time data for each line that can be seen on the graph. I do not have a supplier since I am taking the data directly from the sensor.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I have found that for reasonable-quality data, where you don't need to torture it too much (e.g. you are well above the limit of detection and in a linear region of a calibration curve, and where retention times don't drift too much) it is usually workable to avoid any fancy peak identification and integration algorithms: define peak boundaries by inspection and manually once per data set, and "integrate" just by summing raw intensity values in the boundary.